# AIR Native Process won't launch executables Error #3214 or Error #3219

Tags: windows-7, air, air-native-extension

Pulling my hair out.
Am using

```
<supportedProfiles>extendedDesktop </supportedProfiles>
```

in application descriptor

My pathing is correct to the executable(checked  if exists in code)

Also made sure I give full permissions to my executables, but I still get one of the folllowing errors and the executable won't launch!!

```
Error #3214 or Error #3219
```

In addition when I get Error #3219 I sometimes get

```
Error #3219: The NativeProcess could not be started. 'The requested operation requires elevation.
```

If I double click the executable from the desktop of course it works.

```
>>>>>>Arrgh!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My executable is a wrapped perl file that runs a CHDK hacked camera.

Needed to add the ptpcam.exe as an included file even though that isn't the executable I am targeting

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<supportedProfiles>desktop extendedDesktop</supportedProfiles>
```

Comment: I'll try but I'm fairly certain that only the first value is used. And it must be extendedDesktop.

Comment: And you need to make a native installer when you generate an app.